# Non browser specific elements script record information needed

Tags: jmeter

In order to create a order id, i have to record a Jmeter script for non browser specific elements scenario Steps are(Open Outlook - Click on New mail- Give e-mail id in To field and click on Send  )

Can anyone please suggest how to record a script for above scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter comes with [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) so if your email server supports [SMTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) you can send an email to the given recipient(s) on protocol level without involving any 3rd-party software

[image]

More information: [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Outlook internally uses MAPI protocol to communicate. JMeter does not support this.

You can choose to use Wireshark and capture the packets and then convert it to JMX script through various means (like converters, replay from wireshark and capturing in JMeter etc.) But personally I haven't been able to create an appropriate JMeter script in this manner.

Alternatively, since you require the mail only to generate "order id", you can look at an option of leveraging Outlook's web portal. It should serve the same purpose and you should be able to record the script.